# More than 1 JPanel in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, gridbaglayout

Hello  please see the attached image   ,i am coding  interface that has three JPanels and i am using  `GridBagLayout`  , i have  read   some good tutorials  and got some understanding as well , but  i need your guidance regarding placing 2 JPanels side by side as in given pic .

for example if i  do `frame.add(leftpanel);`  and then there is only one panel on the JFrame .. how to align  it left  on half   of the JFrame  so that when i  do `frame.add(panelright);` it is added to right sid ,

please guide me to   do the  functionality  shown in Pic ,[image]

i can handle  1 JPanel  and all the components  but  dont know abut to handle more than 1 ,

Comment: *"align it left on half of the JFrame"*  ***Exactly*** half?  If so, the left/right panel would require a `GridLayout`.  You might then put that panel in the `CENTER` of a `BorderLayout`, with bottom in `PAGE_END`.

Answer (score 3):

I think in your case `BorderLayout` will be more useful. Try reading about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html).

You can add your panels north south east west or at the center it will be much better than GridBag in this case.

Comment: and in case i have to add 5-6 components in each JPanel that is not that easy for me to  add ,  and in GridBagLayout it is  pretty easy ,  please guide me to add 2 JPandles  or reffer me any resource as i was unable to find it   (for two JPanels)

Comment: yes you can do so by adding another borderlayout in the center or other side layout.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the position and other settings using [GridBagConstraints](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html). 
For example, you could do something like this:

```
GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
constraints.gridx = 0;
constraints.gridy = 0;
constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

frame.add(leftPanel, constraints);
constraints.gridx = 1;
frame.add(panelright, constraints);

constraints.gridx = 0;
constraints.gridy = 1;
constraints.gridwidth = 2;
frame.add(bottomPanel, constraints);
```

GridBagConstraints.gridx and GridBagConstraints.gridy determine the row and column for this element. fill tells the layout to use all the available space both horizontally and vertically.
If you want to set that one cell will use a space with certain proportion relative to other cells, you can use the weightx and weighty fields.

Comment: frame.add(leftPanel, constraints);  it generates error   panel1.add(buttton1, constraints);  this  one works but same way

Comment: I fixed some errors in the code.. What error does it generate? I am supposing you set the JFrame's contentPane to a JPanel with GridBagLayout, right?

Answer (score 2):

Also consider two [`JSplitPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html) instances. The outermost pane would have a `VERTICAL_SPLIT` between top and bottom. The top of the outer pane would contain another `JSplitPane` having a `HORIZONTAL_SPLIT` between left and right.